# Output product with specific bootstrap class name by using php

Tags: php, html, foreach

I got some items draw from database and i wanna display it with specific html class name.

for example::

```
<?php 
$itemsFromDatabase = array(
  array('img' => 'image-1.jpg'),
  array('img' => 'image-2.jpg'),
  array('img' => 'image-3.jpg'),
  array('img' => 'image-4.jpg'),
  array('img' => 'image-5.jpg'),

  array('img' => 'image-6.jpg'),
  array('img' => 'image-7.jpg'),
  array('img' => 'image-8.jpg'),
  array('img' => 'image-9.jpg'),
  array('img' => 'image-10.jpg'),

  // etc...
); 

?>
```

I wanna use php foreach to output the html result like below::

```
<li class="col-md-6"><img src="image-1.jpg" /></li>
<li class="col-md-6"><img src="image-2.jpg" /></li>

<li class="col-md-4"><img src="image-3.jpg" /></li>
<li class="col-md-4"><img src="image-4.jpg" /></li>
<li class="col-md-4"><img src="image-5.jpg" /></li>

<li class="col-md-6"><img src="image-6.jpg" /></li>
<li class="col-md-6"><img src="image-7.jpg" /></li>

<li class="col-md-4"><img src="image-8.jpg" /></li>
<li class="col-md-4"><img src="image-9.jpg" /></li>
<li class="col-md-4"><img src="image-10.jpg" /></li>

.... // will automatic use col-md-6 again when got image-11.jpg in future ...
```

Comment: Great, and you logic you apply here to get result like this?? Did you think any??

Comment: logic: every two record use col-md-4 three time. than repeat

Comment: please ask OP first for the code what he tried so for,then try to give answer

Comment: i think i got solution, thank for you all helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the logic implemented-
Declare two variable, assign `$size = 6`, which is the first size and check that the size is equal to 12 by multiplying with `$times`, if it is then just reset the `$times` and also update the `$size` with alternatives.

```
$size = 6;
$times = 0;
foreach($itemsFromDatabase as $val){
    if(($size * $times++) == 12){
        $size = ($size == 6) ? 4 : 6;
        $times = 1;
    }
    echo '<li class="col-md-'.$size.'">'.$val['img'].'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a couple of counters that get reset when the other reaches the predefined amount seems to give the correct result.

```
$items = array(
    array('img' => 'image-1.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-2.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-3.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-4.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-5.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-6.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-7.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-8.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-9.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-10.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-11.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-12.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-13.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-14.jpg'),
    array('img' => 'image-15.jpg')
);

$i=0;$j=0;
foreach( $items as $item ){
    $img=$item['img'];
    if( $i < 2 ){
        $class='col-md-6';
        $i++;
        if( $j>=3 )$j=0;
    } else {
        $class='col-md-4';
        $j++;

        if( $j >= 3 ){
            $j=0; $i=0;
        }
    }

    echo "<li class='{$class}'><img src='{$img}' /></li>";
}
```

Comment: simple and easy